# VMRC on Ubuntu does not render client area

Tags: gnome, themes, vmware, gtk

I have a problem with my VMware Remote Console (VMRC) 10.0.4 on Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed it on plain Ubuntu and everything had worked perfectly. Then one day I decided to try Pantheon desktop from ppa:elementary-os/stable (according to instruction on this page). Since then my VMRC went astray as you can see

[image: Screenshot]

1. VMRC ignores system themes
2. Client area is filled up with background of VMRC. If I type blindly, characters are sent to the host, so I can even log in using this VMRC, however I can't see anything.

I have a second Ubuntu 18.04 computer with McBuntu themes and VMRC works perfectly.

I have reinstalled VMRC (using official vmware-installer as well as manually removing folders) and different GTK libraries, but nothing works so far. I suspect there is a broken configuration file somewhere in my system. As it is my primary laptop I don't want to reinstall system from scratch.

And something more: when I run command `vmware-installer --gtk -l` I can see a barrage of messages:

```
$ vmware-installer --gtk -l

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(vmware-installer.py:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Product Name         Product Version    

==================== ====================

vmware-vmrc          10.0.4.11818843
```

These errors appear despite overlay-scrollbar and libcanberra-gtk-module as well as Murrine and Adwaita themes are installed. I don't know if these messages have something common with previous problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved my problem:

in the folder `/etc/profile.d/` I had found some scripts from elementary-os theme:

```
gtk-csd.sh 
qt-style-override.sh 
qt-qpa-platformtheme.sh
```

that set some environmental variables (e.g. `export GTK_CSD=1`). I have removed them all and voila, my vmrc works again. Due to my impatience I did not investigated which one of these files actually was the source of the problem, however I surmise it was the first one.

Wojtek